# About using assembly with c

Tags: c, assembly, header-files

I've sort of just finished a mandatory task at school, and I'm about to deliver it.

But then I came across something that was unfamiliar, header files. :(

What I've got:

```
test-program.c
task_header.h
function1.s
function2.s
function3.s
function4.s
```

test-program.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "task_header.h"
.
..
...
```

task_header.h:

```
extern void function1(...);
extern void function2(...);
extern int  function3(...);
extern void function4(...);
```

And then I use the command:

```
gcc -m32 -o runtest test-program.c function1.s function2.s function3.s function4.s
```

**Is this a proper way to do it, or is it possible to modify it? So I can type:**

```
gcc -m32 -o runtest test-program.c
```

**?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfectly reasonable way to do it.

You'd normally write a makefile as well, so that you can just type `make` and not have to remember the build instructions.  Or, perhaps, just a script so you can do a `./build.sh`.

I'll leave those files as an exercise.